# MySql Functions: Insert substring into string

Tags: mysql, string, function, substring

I need to know what function to use to insert a substring into a string of characters in MySql.

This is an example of ua field in my database:

https://www.facebook.com/ExamplePage/

I need to insert the substring **pg/** and it needs to look like this when completed:

https://www.facebook.com/pg/ExamplePage/

Note: the first part of all the strings in my fields are the same.

Comment: IS there a reason you cannot do this with another language such as php, python, javascript that is not SQL?

Comment: post code  not  link to pages that need  authentication

Comment: And what is the general rule for where "pg/" goes?

Comment: Gordon Linoff.... The general rule is it goes directly after facebook.com The end result would be facebook.com/pg/examplepage

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple replacement:

```
update `table` 
set `field` = replace(field, 'https://www.facebook.com/', 'https://www.facebook.com/pg/') 
where `field` like 'https://www.facebook.com/%';
```

Comment: Thanks :D:D:D @mickmackusa